# REST endpoint in Bamboo to create plans?

Tags: rest, automation, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there a way to automate the *creation* and configuration of **new** plans in Bamboo? Some REST endpoint or command-line tool perhaps? I can't find anything in their [REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+REST+Resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildService-SpecificPlan)...

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible with [Bamboo Specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-specs-894743906.html) that was introduced in Bamboo 6.0.

This feature lets you store build plans configuration as code. You can read further here - [What is configuration as code?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/what-is-configuration-as-code-894743909.html).

A short tutorial on this can be found here - [Create a simple plan with Bamboo Specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-specs-894743911.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pay for a [plugin](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ACLI/Atlassian+CLI+license)...boo.